# How to overcome segmentation fault while implementing dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: segmentation-fault, ros, dijkstra, path-finding

I am making a ros node to implement dijkstra's algorithm on a 1000x1000 pixel map.

The map is in the form of a row dominant matrix and I have declared visited, distance and prev in the same form. Distance stores the distance of each index and is initially declared with a huge number. visited is a bool array storing whether that index has been visited or not. prev stores the shortest path followed.

struct node is initialised to make a priority queue storing node and distance in increasing order.

void dijkstra is the function that does the heavy loading in this program. Using gdb, it seems that segmentation fault occurs in this function, however I can not trace it any further.

So, I need help in making sense of this runtime error and any bad practices I may have followed.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#define FMAX 999999999.99


    int rows = 1000, columns = 1000, size = rows * columns;
    bool visited[1000000];
    float distance[1000000];
    int prev[1000000];
    int source = 15100, destination = 990500; // Random source and destination
    int dr[] = {1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1}; // Direction vectors
    int dc[] = {0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1};
    struct node
    {
        int index;
        float dist;
        node(int index, float dist)
            : index(index), dist(dist)
        {
        } 
    };
    struct compareDist
    {
        bool operator()(node const& n1, node const& n2)
        {
            return n1.dist > n2.dist;
        }
    };

    // Priority queue
    std::priority_queue <node, std::vector<node>, compareDist> pq;

    int index(int r, int c)
    {
        return (r * 1000) + c;
    }

    void init()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            distance[i] = FMAX;
            visited[i] = false;
            prev[i] = 9999999;
        }   
    }

    float dist_(int index1, int index2)
    {
        int r1, c1, r2, c2;
        r1 = index1 / columns; r2 = index2 / columns;
        c1 = index1 - (r1 * 1000); c2 = index2 - (r2 * 1000);
        return sqrt(pow(r1 - r2, 2) + pow(c1 - c2, 2));
    }

    void dijkstra(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
    {
        prev[source] = 0;
        node first = {source, 0.0}; 
        pq.push(first);
        while(!pq.empty())
        {

            node temp = pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            int nodeIndex = temp.index;
            float nodeDist = temp.dist;

            visited[nodeIndex] = true;
            int r = nodeIndex / columns;
            int c = nodeIndex - (r * columns);
            int rr, cc;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // to calculate neighbours
            {
                rr = r + dr[i];
                cc = c + dc[i];

                if(map.data[index(rr, cc)] == 100)
                    visited[index(rr, cc)] = true; // Marking blocked paths as visited

                if(rr < 0 || rr >= 1000 || cc < 0 || cc >= 1000 || visited[index(rr, cc)] == true)
                    continue;


                else
                {
                    node neighbour(index(rr, cc), dist_(nodeIndex, index(rr, cc)));
                    float alt = nodeDist + neighbour.dist;
                    if(alt < distance[index(rr, cc)])
                    {
                        visited[index(rr, cc)] = true;
                        distance[index(rr, cc)] = alt;
                        prev[index(rr, cc)] = nodeIndex;
                        node next(index(rr, cc), alt);

                        pq.push(next);
                    }
                    if(visited[destination] == true)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(visited[destination] == true)
                break;
        }
        std::vector <int> path;
        // prev contains the path. Trace it back to get the path.
        path.push_back(destination);
        while(true)
        {
            path.push_back(prev[path.back()]);
            if(path.back() == 0)
                break;
        }

        geometry_msgs::PoseArray poseArray;
        poseArray.header.frame_id = "map"; // or other frame you wish to publish relative to.
        std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> pose_vector;
        // push or insert to your vector
        for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
        {
            geometry_msgs::Pose p;
            p.position.x = path.back();
            pose_vector.push_back(p);
        }
        poseArray.poses = pose_vector;
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::Publisher pose_array_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);
        pose_array_pub.publish(poseArray);

    }



    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "dijkstra");
        ros::NodeHandle n("~");
        ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/map", 1000, dijkstra);

        init();
        distance[source] = 0;
        visited[source] = true;
        ros::spin();    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile your code with debugging symbols and then run it in the debugger.
This will should you exactly where the error occurs and allow you to examine the state of the program at the point of the crash.